# Objective C - The meaning of this Method and line of code?

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks, semantics

First,

```
 + (void)allOpenRequestsWithBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *requests, NSError *error))block
```

Can someone give an in depth explanation what the semantics of this method is?
What is the plus sign vs minus.
Can someone explain (void (^)(NSArray *requests, NSError *error))block?
It's a void block that retains requests and errors?

This line of code:

```
 [[AFChangeRequestAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:@"example.json" parameters:[NSDictionary      dictionaryWithObject:@"false" forKey:@"include_entities"] success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON)
```

Is this calling the get Path Method that has parameters above? THe Dictionary is passed with just 1 key/value of include_entities/false? What does the success block part mean? Is it the return value?

I am basically trying to understand the AFNetworking framework and it seems to use syntax that I am not familiar with.

Thanks!
Alan

Comment: If you don't understand the meaning of `-` and `+` (i.e. instance or class methods) you should hold-off on learning the AFNetworking Framework until you have learned Objective-C itself.  Start here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very vast question. You shouldn't expect to learn a language simply by example, and should read the [Introduction to Objective-C Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) in Apple's documentation first before going further. By asking the question you seem to try to understand everything at the same time whereas you don't seem to know the basics of the language itself, and this is not the good approach to learn a language.

To answer your question anyway:

- The `+` sign means it is a class method. The `-` sign means it is an instance method.
- The semantic of a method is `- (returntype)methodName:(type1)param1 nameContinuation:(type2)param2 ;` where the `-` here thus means it is an instance method, the return type is `returntype`, the method has the name `methodName:nameContinuation:` and has two parameters, one of type `type1` identified by the variable `param1` and one of the type `type2` identified with the variable `param2`
- In the `+ (void)allOpenRequestsWithBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *requests, NSError *error))block`
   synthax, then, `void(^)(NSArray* requests, NSError* error)` is the type of the first parameter. This type describes an **Objective-C block**, which is something quite similar to a function pointer but that allows closure (and variable capture). For more info about blocks, again, [read the dedicated Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/_index.html).

---

For the second question, the method call is not complete and miss the block body.

```
[[AFChangeRequestAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:@"example.json"
                                      parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"false" forKey:@"include_entities"]
                                         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON)
 {
   /* block body here */
 }];
```

This calls the method `getPath:parameters:success:` on the object returned by `[AFChangeRequestAPIClient sharedClient]` (so this is not AT ALL the same method as above). This method is passed three parameters, the first one being `@"example.json"`, the second one being an `NSDictionary` containing only one key/value pair, and the last one being a Objetive-C block. This block takes two parameters of type `AFHTTPRequestOperation` and `id` respectively.

*Again, it really seems that you try to learn stuff too fast and use advanced stuffs (like blocks and their syntax) before understanding the basics (like instance vs. class methods, the basic language syntax of a method, etc). Take your time to learn stuff, you don't build a house in one day, and more important you build the foundation before the roof ;)*

Answer (score 1):

The plus sign indicates a class level method, minus would mean an instance method.

Blocks are similar to functions. That block has two parameters (an `NSArray*` and an `NSError*`) and 'returns' `void`.

For the second question I cannot answer you completely.

I do not know that framework and you post a line of code, but that line is missing something (at least the block body is not there).